# RegEx to randomly set case of characters in a string

Tags: regex, string

What I'm looking for is a RegEx to mix the character case of a given string for use in functional testing.

Example Input:

```
The Quick Brown fox jumps over the Lazy Dog.
```

Sample Expected Output:

```
tHe QUiCk BrOwn FoX jUMPs OvER tHe lAzY dOg.
```

It would be nice if the output was different every time the RegEx were applied. For example, given the above input, another time the RegEx were applied, the output could be:

```
THe qUIcK bROwN fOX JuMpS oVeR THe lAzy DoG.
```

I know that it would be easy to simply set up a substitution table (e.g., 'x' => 'X', 'B' => 'b'), but that is not what I'm looking for.

I did a Google search for this and came up with nothing, although I know it has been done. I had code (now lost) that did this.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't loop through the characters in the string and randomly set case that way? What language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in perl this works

perl -e '$_="The Quick Brown fox jumps over the Lazy Dog";s/([a-zA-Z])/rand()<.5 ? uc($1) : lc($1)/ge;print'

ran it a few times...

- ThE quIck bRowN FOx juMPs OVer the
  lAzy DoG
- ThE QuiCK brOWN FoX jUmpS oVER THE
  LazY Dog
- thE QuICK brOwN FOx JumpS OvEr the
  LAZY dOg
- the quicK BroWN Fox JUMPS OVEr The
  laZY DoG
- THe QUICk brown FOX juMPS OvEr tHe
  LAzy doG
- The qUick Brown FoX jUMps oVeR THe
  LAzy Dog
- the QuiCK broWn fOx jumPs oveR The
  LAzy doG
- tHE QUicK browN fOx jumpS OVer the
  LaZY dOG

Answer (score 4):

`RegEx` is supposed to do something deterministic and not random. In C# you could achieve it using something like this:

```
var random = new Random();
var result = new string(((IEnumerable<char>)input.ToLowerInvariant())
              .Select(x => random.Next(2) == 0 ? x : Char.ToUpperInvariant(x))
              .ToArray());
```

Comment: Seriously. The simple answer is "Don't."

Comment: @Daniel: I can think of some possible use cases for spammers ;)

Comment: Thanks for that -- however C# is OS-specific. I'm not running this on a Window machine; mostly it will run on a headless Linux box (installing X + Wine / Mono just to run a functional test is not going to happen).

Comment: BryanH: Can't agree. It's hardly OS specific. Mono is in default installation of Ubuntu nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are great, but they are not always the best solution.

Here is some simple pseudo-script to do what you want:

The only regex here is in the split function - to convert to an array of characters.
Since many languages will let you treat a string as an array of characters anyway, that bit might not even be necessary.

```
MyArray = MyString.split('[\b\B]')

for each ( Character in MyArray )
{
    if ( Random(0,1) > 0.5 )
    {
         Character = Uppercase(Character)
    }
    else
    {
         Character = Lowercase(Character)
    }
}

MyString = MyArray.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be a regexp.  In Python:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> a = "lorem ipsum dolor sic amet"
>>> ''.join(choice((c.lower, c.upper))() for c in a)
'LoREM ipSum DoloR sic AmEt'
```